# Bootstrap 4.4.1 dropdown does not work in ASP.NET MVC view

Tags: asp.net-mvc, bootstrap-4, dropdown

I am trying to display a dropdown using the following code. When I click on the dropdown, the dropdown items are not visible.

Here is the code for my view:

```
@{DateTime curDay = Convert.ToDateTime(ViewBag.StartDate).AddDays(dayName).Date;}
<div class="dropdown">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
            @curDay.ToString("dddd, MMMM dd, yyyy")
        </button>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            @{for (i = 1; i <= maxWorkingDay; i++)
                {
                    string tmpDay = Convert.ToDateTime(ViewBag.StartDate).AddDays(i).ToString("dddd, MMMM dd, yyyy");
                    if (i == dayName)
                    {
                        <li class="active dropdown-item ">@Html.ActionLink(tmpDay, "", new { })</li>
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        <li class="dropdown-item"> @Html.ActionLink(tmpDay, "", new { }) </li>
                    }
                }
            }
        </ul>
    </div>
```

However when I tried to inspect the page after clicking the dropdown, I can see that the dropdown item is hidden. It can be seen in the following screenshot.

How can I make this visible?

[image]

Comment: Check style window on the Element inspection window.

Comment: Have you tried it without using bootstrap classes? just to make sure the problem is in fact the styles?

Comment: @Andres2142 yes another razor dropdown is working fine.